# Styling checklist from model

Tags: html, css, tapestry

I have a checklist that is generated from a model. The model is fairly large thus quite a few checkboxes are created. With that said I can't seem to find a way through CSS or otherwise that these can be generated to have multiple columns/rows so the list doesn't just span down the page.

Code (if necessary)

```
<t:Checklist t:id="preference" t:model="preferences" t:selected="prefSelectedValues" t:encoder="stringValueEncoder" />
```

Comment: Have you tried multi-column layouts? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts

Comment: @DmitryGusev that was a great solution thank you